# Sums and products of infinite transformations of functions

Tags: sequences-and-series

Ever since I learned about $$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\frac1{x+\pi n}=\cot x$$I've wanted to know more about infinite sums and products of different functions. {Extremely laggy, takes a lot of time to load, may crash} [Here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/3vrdmlzlx7) are some functions I found. Let me know if you'd like to know how I found them. You may want to turn some of the graphs off to see them in all their glory.

If somebody could direct me towards a resource on this I'd greatly appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: I suggest you read a course in Complex Analysis, focus especially on the Residue theorem. This is how is derived the equality you mentioned on the cotangent.